# Can you identify this mold? (Aspergillus?)

Tags: species-identification

I took some macro pictures (see below) of some black mold growing on wet straw. I noticed this creature that I think to be [Aspergillus niger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspergillus_niger), but looks bigger than the one depicted in [many pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=aspergillus%20niger&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi--YnwuvzhAhVNDuwKHW18DvgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1825&bih=911) (the fruiting body is visible by naked eys) and since I am not an expert mycologist, I would like to ask the following questions:

- Do you think it is Aspergillus niger?
- If not what it is?
- Is it dangerous (toxic/poisonous/infective) to keep it growing for the sake of making pictures?

Update. I am still getting this mold infection running on some of my cultures. Eventually, I managed to add some extra pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the pic of growth? Normal shot not the macro one?

Comment: @AmodBhat Those are all the pictures I got. I trashed everything since a cloud of spores would be released after any vibration and I preferred not taking any risk. The first and the last pictures represent the colonies well though.

Comment: @AmodBhat Eventually, I got an ordinary pic of it. The piece of straw is about 4cm long.

Comment: I though it might be aspergillius niger also, but since it appears to be growing somewhat like a filament i would think it could be some sort of rhizopus. Aspergillus niger can produce mycotoxins (some strains) but generally it's safe. If it is rhizopus, the only health problem can occur if you're immunocompromized, but i'd be carful not to inhale or get near eyes. Also be careful not to spread spores (shaking, etc...). Mold can be persistent and hard to get rid of. Look into Rhizopus stolonife which is black bread mold.

Comment: @m4rio I am not convinced. The pic I find about Rhizopus are all microscopic ones. The fruiting bodies of this mold are visible with naked eye. Can you back up your conclusion with some pics?